# Custom workflow step inconsistent behavior

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I've made a custom workflow step which sends email to the group of users. I take precreated email and send it programmatically:

```
if (recepients.Entities.Any())
    {
        Entity email = service.Retrieve("email", mailId, new ColumnSet(true));

        email.Attributes["to"] = recepients.Entities.ToArray();

        service.Update(email);

        SendEmailRequest sendEmail = new SendEmailRequest()
        {
           EmailId = mailId,
           IssueSend = true
        };

        service.Execute(sendEmail);
    }
```

The problem is - it works just fine in sync mode, and throw an "Invalid Cast" exception if i convert workflow into async and try to run it.

Here what trace log on the server provides:

```
>System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #EBCA9EC1: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

>   at Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel.TrackingManager.GetNextTrackingToken(String subject, String& trackingToken)

>   at Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel.EmailService.Send(Guid emailId, Boolean issueSend, String trackingToken, ExecutionContext context)
```

Somehow error occurs during converting results of the workflow. Where should I look to find the root of this problem?

```
        at WorkflowToAsyncResultConverter.Convert(WorkflowSystemPausedResult wfResult)  ilOffset = 0x23
        at WorkflowToAsyncResultConverter.Convert()  ilOffset = 0x9D

        at WorkflowContext.EndProcessing(IGenericHandlerResult result)  ilOffset = 0xC

        at ActivityHost.CompleteWorkflow(IGenericHandlerResult result, WorkflowApplication activityInstance, ICommonWorkflowContext context)  ilOffset = 0x70

        at ActivityHostBase.OnWorkflowTerminated(WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args, WorkflowApplication activityInstance, ICommonWorkflowContext context)  ilOffset = 0x8F

        at UnhandledExceptionEventHandler.OnStage1Complete(IAsyncResult lastResult, WorkflowApplication instance, Exception exception, Activity source, String sourceInstanceId)  ilOffset = 0x46

        at UnhandledExceptionEventHandler.Run(WorkflowApplication instance, Exception exception, Activity exceptionSource, String exceptionSourceInstanceId)  ilOffset = 0x78

        at WorkflowApplication.OnNotifyUnhandledException(Exception exception, Activity exceptionSource, String exceptionSourceInstanceId)  ilOffset = 0x23

        at ActivityExecutor.NotifyUnhandledException(Exception exception, ActivityInstance source)  ilOffset = 0x18

        at Scheduler.OnScheduledWork(Object state)  ilOffset = 0x123

        at SendOrPostThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(Object state)  ilOffset = 0x0

        at ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  ilOffset = 0x22

        at IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  ilOffset = 0x5

        at _IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)  ilOffset = 0x3C
```

Comment: How do you get the service in your custom workflow step? Is it running in the context of the executing user?

Comment: @Henrik  I get factory out of execution context, and then create an instance of IOrganizationService with SYSTEM privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an OrganizationService running as the executing user, instead of SYSTEM. A similar issue with the core email operation has been experienced by [Andrii Butenko, who concluded that it works when running the service in the context of the executing user.](http://butenko.pro/2012/05/ms-crm-2011-strange-error-during-sending-of-an-email-from-plugin/)

> I have changed instantiation of service to running user and everything worked without any issues:
>
> ```cs
>  IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = 
>      (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
>  IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(executioncontext.UserId);
> ```